# how can i get client MAC address? (in jsp,java)

Tags: java, jsp

i want to get client MAC address (in jsp,java)

it's possible? how to do?

thanks for help

Comment: Only if there's no routers between your site and the client--the MAC address exists on packets, but the value gets updated with the MAC for every broadcast device the packet passes through.

Comment: You'll have this same issue with any language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible directly in JSP because it will not be passed as part of the HTTP Header. You would need to have some client side script to run, that has access to the network adapter to find this information.

I am not sure if an applet would be able to get this for you, but this would need extended permissions if it were possible, and a user is unlikely to allow it.

Comment: @donroby, "unfortunately" that I couldn't answer the question with what Zenofo wanted, rather than MAC addresses being easily collected via Web traffic (which would be very very bad).

Answer (score 1):

Why? Are you aware they can be changed by intermediiate routers? And users? So they are of no practical use except to the network layer?